# Android Custom EditText Cursor

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Good Afternoon,

I have created a custom EditText Box for my app, but am having a little bit of trouble with it. My main problem is when the user initially clicks on the box the cursor does not show up. After entering some text though the cursor will become visible. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Here is my current XML code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox1"
    android:gravity = "bottom"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.